# How to print BSSID in IOS5.1 such that everytime a new AP is detected within same SSID, the new value of BSSID is printed

Tags: xcode, ios5

My code (compiles without errors) which I took from another post in StackOverflow and modified:

```
NSError *error; 
NSArray *ifs = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(CNCopySupportedInterfaces());
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
id info = nil;

for (NSString *ifnam in ifs)
{
    info = (NSDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam));
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);

    if (info && [info count])
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code on an iOS 5.01. It does not work for me.
I notice a handover takes place. I'll explain. My two access points, having the same ssid, are actually two routers I can ping from my iphone.
Here's the scenario:

1. I am initially connected to router A. I can ping the IP of router A. And the code displays A's BSSID.
2. I move into the range of router B, and out of the range of router A. I can no longer ping router A, but I can now ping router B. The code goes on displaying A's BSSID.

Although the handover has been made, CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo does not return fresh data.
Here's a possible answer as to why that happens:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304701