# iphone app can't see internal network

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, ssid

I'm working on an Enterprise app that communicates with our company servers. I have full two-way communication between the phone and the server through 3G/4G, and it works from my home wifi, but using the wifi at the office where it is connected to the company network the app doesn't see the server that way.

The app is set to look for our external IP address, and the port is open to the server. But I guess the external IP address is not 'visible' from within the network. When I plug in the *internal* IP address of the server, it goes through just fine.

For the vast number of our users, that would not be a problem. Most of our users (employees) work in the field or in other offices. But for users inside our network, this arrangement is useless unless the user turned off his wifi. But that's not a professional way to do it.

I need to know if there's a way for my app to either use 3G/4G exclusively, or to discover the SSID of the wifi and decide which IP address to use. I'm guessing that the answers to both of these will be, "you can't do that," But I thought I'd ask anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followup: ceejayoz, I don't know if your second suggestion is the same as what our IT guy did, but he created a domain name that will resolve to the server whether it's internal or external. That seems to be the best way to go. So even though I had a workable answer, the URL works better with less code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have it attempt the internal IP, and fall back to the external IP if it can't connect. A better solution might be to have an internal DNS server that serves the internal IP to in-network devices, though.

Comment: Thanks... I tested your first suggestion and found that the timeout for searching for a network is more than a minute. I think if we could reduce the timeout to maybe five seconds, and then switch, it would be workable. As for the internal DNS server, I'll check with our IT Administrator for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698039/am-i-using-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo-correctly) is exactly what I need. It gives me the SSID in string form, and I can compare the SSID string with a string of our wifi's SSID, and if it matches then the app uses the internal IP address. And if it doesn't match, it will connect to the external IP address. So far it works perfectly!